# forEach returning undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

This function goes through the arrays and in each object, add the 1st number and subtract the 2nd number

eg. number([[10,0],[3,5],[5,8]]) = (10-0) + (3-5) + (5-8) Total should equal 5

Problem: I'm using a forEach loop but it returns undefined, when I console.log the number shows 5.

```
var number = function(busStops){
  var total = 0;
  busStops.forEach(function(n){
    total = total + n[0] - n[1];
    return total;
  })
}
```

Comment: [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not use any return value. take [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

Comment: The return statement should not be in the loop. You can try to put it after the closing bracket and parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array.

```js
const
    number = busStops => busStops.reduce((t, [a, b]) => t + a - b, 0);

console.log(number([[10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue, the return should be outside the forEach loop

```
var number = function(busStops){
  var total = 0;
  busStops.forEach(function(n){
    total = total + n[0] - n[1];
  })
  return total;
}
```